# How can the overvoltage prodection inhibit the voltage to let the voltage doesn't reach the destrutive level?

Tags: voltage, schematics, over-voltage-protection

[image]

This is the voltage conditioning schematic,including OVP(overvoltage prodection) and LDO(low drop-out regulator),the OVP limits \$V_{buck}\$ to inhibit it reaching destrutive voltage level.

When \$V_{buck}\$ exceeds the limit voltage,the \$M_{OVP}\$ will be drived,and question is,"so"?i mean,i just turn on a MOS,how can it save something?

According to the explaination,the exceeding \$V_{buck}\$ must damage something,and it seems OVP rescue that "something",just like the fire burn the house,and the water  extinguish and save the house.

I know the fire is exceeding \$V_{buck}\$,and the water is OVP,but now,who is the house,LDO?

Comment: No, the House is on the ground, its the M_LDO that could burn from overload , which in your house,  is on the roof. but if the LDO sensed current, it could squirt water up the CG to prevent the M from burning.

Comment: If Movp channel resistance is low enough when active, Vbuck is essentialy short-circuited to ground ("dousing the flames" - to keep with the metaphor).

Comment: So you mean when the \$M_{OVP}\$ turn on,it will conduct some current to the ground,so the current ,flow to the \$M_{LDO}\$,will be less,and won't damage the \$M_{LDO}\$?

Comment: Yes, the better way to think it is that Movp would drop the input impedance of the circuit, to the point which the source of Vbuck could no longer provide the output power required to keep the overvoltage. I'll write a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following circuit. It might not be even remotely close to the same circuit, but it suffices to explain the OVP part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmqUDM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When Movp is cutoff (normal operation - no overvoltage), it is equivalent to this circuit when Rovp is very high, to the point that it could be considered infinite for any practical analysis. The voltage Vbuck is therefore given as a ratio of the voltage source, nominally Rldo/(Rldo+Rbuck), and power consumed by LDO is $$\frac{Vbuck^2}{Rldo}$$

When Movp is activated (overvoltage detected), then Rovp in our circuit goes down. If it essentially becomes a short circuit, Vbuck goes to 0, ending the overvoltage. If the channel resistance Rovp is still to be considered, then 
the total power consumed by LDO and OVP will become $$\frac{Vbuck^2}{Rldo} + \frac{Vbuck^2}{Rovp}$$

The circuit designer then expects this total output power to be too much for the overvoltage source to handle, killing the overvoltage.

Comment: I don't understand very well at the last part   "The circuit designer then expects this total output power to be too much for the overvoltage source to handle, killing the overvoltage."

Comment: If the overvoltage were to be maintained, a very high current would need to go through Movp. If the source can deliver such a current, then the overvoltage will not be affected. It is then expected, by the designer, that the overvoltage source cannot deliver such a current.

Comment: if the ratio of W/L is smaller,the /$r_o/$ will be smaller too?

Comment: Yes, channel resistance goes up with channel length, and goes down with channel width. Just like a regular copper wire behaves.

Comment: This is a form of crowbar or shunt regulator. It is assumed that the source of over-voltage has a limited ability to supply current. So when Movp turns on, the Voltage at Vbuck will drop very rapidly. If you connected a car battery to Vbuck, Movp would probably overheat and fail. But presumably Vbuck cannot supply enough current to destroy Movp.

Comment: This model is misleading, which  assumes incorrectly load is a short circuit when in fact Rload must be  shown.  Max power transfer occurs when load matches source impedance, but due to size, the source LDO cannot handle the power, so Ron of LDO must be << R Load and R_ovp must be low enough to attenuate and large enough to absorb E[J] of each peak cycle V(t)*I(t) * t. For a good design, optimal values are near Ron=1% Rload (min) for 1% step load regulation error. Please fix it

Comment: otherwise XM551 will be misleading others by accepting this with good but not quite correct answers